# Can we solve 4 unknows with 3 equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

> recently I am solving this 3 equations:
> $$\begin{cases}
> w+y+x+z=0\\
> w-y+x-z=2\\
> wy+xz=0\\
> \end{cases}
> $$

I can get
$$x=1-w$$
However, when I put $x = 1 - w$ into different equations, I can't still get the result.
There is no any restrictions of $w,x,y$ and $z$. How can I solve those unknowns? Thank you.

Comment: You use the tag `linear-algebra`. But this is not a linear system of equations. And how did you get $x=1-w$?

Comment: @mrsamy : Adding the first two equations gives you $x = 1 - w$

Comment: @MPW: ah, yes..

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that there are infinitely many solutions. If you are looking for integer solutions: $w = 0, y = -1, x = 1, z = 0$ and $w = 1, y = 0, x = 0, z = -1$ both seem to work. By substitution $x$, $y$, $z$ can be expressed in terms of $w$: $$x=1-w$$
$$y=\frac{1-w}{2w-1}$$
$$z=-\frac{w}{2w-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

First of all this is not a linear system. The third equation is a $2$nd degree equation.

Furthermore it has not a unique solution, because to have one and only one solution a necessary condition is that the number of equations was at least equal to the number of unknowns.

Anyway, if you add the first two equations you get
$$2w+2x=2\to w=1-x$$
then you substitute in the first and get
$$ x-x+y+z+1=0\to z=-1-y$$
the third equation becomes
$$(1 - x) y + x (-1 - y) =0$$
and you solve wrt $x$
$$x=\frac{y}{2 y+1};\;z=-y-1,w= \frac{y+1}{2 y+1}$$